# Отмена закрытия консоли в C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Как отменить закрытие консоли после выполненных мною действий. Делаю примитивный калькулятор.

```
using System;
class Calculator
{
    public static void Main()
    { int x; //Переменная, которая задается пользователем для выбора операции.
        string str; //Строка, в которую будет вводиться нужная операция
        float result;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите номер операции \n 1) Сложение \n 2) Вычитание \n 3) Умножение \n 4 Деление \n Ожидание ввода:");

        str = Console.ReadLine();
        x = Convert.ToInt32(str);
        if (x == 1)

        {
            string srt1;
            string srt2;
            float x1;
            float x2;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");
            srt1 = Console.ReadLine();
            x1 = Convert.ToInt32(srt1);
            Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число:");
            srt2 = Console.ReadLine();
            x2 = Convert.ToInt32(srt2);
            Console.WriteLine("Сумма равна:");
            result = x1 + x2;
            Console.WriteLine(result);


        }
        else
        { if (x == 2)
            {
                string srt1;
                string srt2;
                float x1;
                float x2;

                Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число:");
                srt1 = Console.ReadLine();
                x1 = Convert.ToInt32(srt1);
                Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число:");
                srt2 = Console.ReadLine();
                x2 = Convert.ToInt32(srt2);
                Console.WriteLine("Произведение равно:");
                result = x1 * x2;
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else
            { Console.WriteLine("Ошибка"); }


            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Добавьте `Console.ReadKey();` перед закрывающей "}" функции `Main`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я правильно понимаю, что после выполнения моей операции при нажатии клавиши (любой) закрывается консоль. А как сделать так, чтобы она закрывалась, например, при вводе определенного числа?

Comment: Вы же уже знаете про `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Я не понимаю о чем Вы. Можно поподробнее?

Comment: `while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit") { }`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов в программировании!

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
class Calculator
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        while(Console.ReadLine() != "exit")
        {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

по кругу будет крутится калькулятор пока не напишешь exit.